# vscode unable to find executable for

Tags: vscode-debugger

I suddenly am unable to run and compile any code in Vscide, When I try I get the following error message.

unable to find executable for '</home/dennis/Programs/cpp/'

The launch.json reads

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/<executable file>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am running linux mint 21.

It was working fine and then it suddenly stopped working. Something changed and I'm not sure what changed.

vscode about data.

Version: 1.73.0
Commit: 8fa188b2b301d36553cbc9ce1b0a146ccb93351f
Date: 2022-11-01T15:44:09.336Z
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-52-generic
Sandboxed: No

Can some one help me.

I tried running previouslly ran code that worked in vscode and they suddenly do not work

Comment: tried a test program and using gcc test.cpp and it reports one error